# How can I distribute a visual studio solution that references a class library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, setup-project

I have a visual studio solution written using VB.net.

The solution contains 4 projects.

1. A GUI
2. A Service
3. A Settings library
4. A WiX Setup project

Here's how it used to work.

Last week, I had no shared settings library, and all was fine. But, because both the GUI and the Service contained an identical class named ConfigXML.vb (for serializing and deserializing settings), which I was regularly making changes to and copying and pasting between projects, I decided to extract the class into a library project of it's own (3 above).

This week, nothing works!

I added project references to 1. and 2. and things do work the same as they ever did. When I "start debugging" I can see and use the GUI as normal.

However, the problem I have is that when I create and install a new Setup of the solution, both the GUI and the Service fail to start.

I presume that the problem is the settings library is no longer where it was expected to be / hasn't been registered properly, needs to be placed in a directory by the Setup.msi or something similar.

This is my first time doing something like this, so I expect it's an obvious fix that I need.

Comment: When the class library is built and your executable project has it marked as a dependancy, the DLL should be copied to the same directory.

Comment: OK, that works! Is there a way to stop me needing to copy the dll to the exe dir of both the projects?

Comment: Add it as a dependancy. In VS2010: Right click the project -> Add Reference -> Projects -> Select the DLL project -> OK.

Comment: When you are creating setup project then add your dependencies also in your setup project then it will copy them automatically in your exe location path..

Comment: @Polynomial, I've already done that, it works. 

But the issue is that the setup project installs 2 applications, a GUI and a Server. As per your advice to fix my problem, I placed the .dll file into the install dir of a client machine (where the broken software is installed and failing) and it works. To fix the service, the .dll must also be placed into the service install dir. This is the solution to my problem.

For the sake or reducing duplication, my final question is, do you know a way to put the .dll in a central place once, rather than duplicate it to 2 separate folders?

Answer (score 0):

I gather from the name of that class "...XML.vb" that there is an XML file that lives along side this class on disc.  If there is such a file, then you need to add that file to the project and then right click on it go to "Properties" and set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if Newer"

Comment: I don't think that this is relevant to the issue I outlined in my question. The application worked fine prior to extracting the library, the XML file is created successfully on installation. Are you sure this will solve my problem?